# Hidden mistake in string manipulation

Tags: python, scikit-learn

When running the following code snippet:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

credit = pd.read_csv('credit_data_risk.csv')
del credit['Unnamed: 0']
numerical_credit = credit.select_dtypes(exclude='O')

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import numpy as np

scaler = StandardScaler()
scaled_credit = scaler.fit_transform(numerical_credit)

distance = []
for k in range(1, 10):
  kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=k)
  kmeans.fit(scaled_credit)
  distance.append(kmeans.inertia_)
```

I get the following error message (by kmeans.fit):

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

The dataset seems to be OK. I do not operate directly any string manipulation...
Why, please?

Comment: There is no line in the above code that makes a call to `split`. So either you hve not shown all the code, or the error message refers to a line in a different module. But in either case something has passed a `None` reference to some method which thinks it is a `srting` reference.

Comment: It's clearly imported module complaining, stack trace? I've used pandas but I'm not going to read through both tool's documentation

Comment: I strongly suspect you should look at your `csv` files.  It probably has blank entries which are being interpreted as None.

Comment: @Frank Yellin, could NAs produce that kind of error? thanks.

Comment: Why are you asking me?  Look at `credit` and see if it has any `None`s in it.